# How to use a variable to read back into a Tkinter text box?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyvisa

Thanks to help from a previous question I now have the following code which works.  I am able to print my response to the shell, but is there a way to update that response into label3?

```
    from tkinter import *

    instr = ""
    class Application():


        def __init__(self, master):

            self.master = master
            root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
            self.label1 = Label(master, text="Enter UUT Address")
            self.label1.pack()
            self.entry1 = Entry(self.master)
            self.entry1.pack()
            self.button1 = Button(self.master, text = "Query Instrument", width = 25, command = self.query_instrument)
            self.button1.pack()
            self.button2 = Button(self.master, text = 'Quit', width = 25, command = self.close_windows)
            self.button2.pack()
            self.label2 = Label(master, text= "Instrument Response")
            self.label2.pack()
            self.label3 = Label(master, text= instr)
            self.label3.pack()

     def close_windows(self):
            self.master.destroy()    

     def query_instrument(self):
            addr = self.entry1.get()
            import visa
            rm = visa.ResourceManager()
            rm.list_resources()
            ('ASRL1::INSTR', 'ASRL2::INSTR', 'GPIB0::' + str(addr) + '::INSTR')
             my_instrument = rm.open_resource('GPIB0::' + str(addr) + '::INSTR')
             global instr
             instr = my_instrument.query('*IDN?')
             print (instr)


    root = Tk()
    Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you done any research at all before asking this question? There are many questions on stackoverflow about how to update a label, and the features to do so are documented in almost all tkinter documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update any label by using the `config()` method.

So instead of printing the value you can configure the text argument directly with `config(text=instr)`

Change:

```
print (instr)
```

To:

```
self.label3.config(text = instr)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you again for all your assistance.

Comment: @Joe.M If my answer works for you please select the check box next to my answer to indicate you problem has been solved.